# How do I merge a custom database to Drupal?

Tags: sql-server, drupal

I'm completely new to MSSQL, and need to merge a database from a news site that we've developed in ASP.net to a new Drupal server. I've been looking online for a few days now and haven't come to any helpful results or tutorial. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158494/importing-and-exporting-data-from-an-asp-net-based-web-app-to-drupal) is sort of related, but I only need to do a one-way one-time transfer of the data. How do I go about doing the export and the remapping of the old data into Drupal's layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "easy" way.

These two modules are probably your best bet.

1. [Migrate Module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate)
2. [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)

So first install and set-up Drupal the way you would like.
then use both or either of the above modules to transfer the various parts of the MSSQL database to Drupal, you will need to read the documentation for both of those modules to decide how you should do it.